# getting data from two different tables that have only one common column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My tables are as follows:

Please give me an SQL query to get the expected result set.

```
Table1                  
A   B   C   D   E   
1   2   C1  D1  E1  
2   2   C2  D2  E2  
3   2   C3  D3  E3  


Table2                  
A   B   F   G   H   
1   2   F1  G1  H1  
2   2   F2  G2  H2  
3   5   F3  G3  H3  
4   6   F4  G4  H4
```

Expected Result :

```
B   C       D       E       F       G       H
2   C1      D1      E1      NULL    NULL    NULL
2   C2      D2      E2      NULL    NULL    NULL
2   C3      D3      E3      NULL    NULL    NULL
2   NULL    NULL    NULL    F1      G1      H1
2   NULL    NULL    NULL    F2      G2      H2
```

Comment: Any attempts so far? What is the logic at all? This site is about fixing other people's code (or sql) that doesn't work. It's not about doing their whole work.

Comment: Whats the logic behind that result

Comment: What u try so far ? Edit your Q plz & put some code

Comment: In fact, I don't think this question related to `join`, probably you should use `union`

Comment: I think `JOIN` will work.

Answer (score 1):

You need [UNION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) to combine results of two or more queries as below. As you have `C, D, E` in one table and they are not present in another you need to add this columns with `NULL` values, the same to `F, G, H`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  B,   
            C,   
            D,   
            E, 
            NULL F, 
            NULL G, 
            NULL H  
    FROM Table1 t1
    UNION
    SELECT  B,  
            NULL C,
            NULL D, 
            NULL E,  
            F,   
            G,   
            H  
    FROM Table2 t2
) t
WHERE B = 2
```

Output:

```
B   C       D       E       F       G       H
2   C1      D1      E1      NULL    NULL    NULL
2   C2      D2      E2      NULL    NULL    NULL
2   C3      D3      E3      NULL    NULL    NULL
2   NULL    NULL    NULL    F1      G1      H1
2   NULL    NULL    NULL    F2      G2      H2
```